# Web Application based on Spring Security crashes during startup (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My application, which make use of Spring Security, is crashing during the startup. Tracking the execution of the application, I could verify the error is happening in method onStartup from class MainWebAppInitializer:

```
public class MainWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    /**
     * Register and configure all Servlet container components necessary to power the web application.
     */
    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        root.scan("com.spring.web.config");

        // Manages the lifecycle of the root application context
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));

        // Handles requests into the application
        final ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = sc.addServlet("horariolivreapp", new DispatcherServlet(new GenericWebApplicationContext()));
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        final Set<String> mappingConflicts = appServlet.addMapping("/");
        if (!mappingConflicts.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("'appServlet' could not be mapped to '/' due " + "to an existing mapping. This is a known issue under Tomcat versions " + "<= 7.0.14; see https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51278");
        }
    }

}
```

More specificly, the error occurs in the line

```
appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1)
```

where a NullPointerException is triggered. Follow it is my configuration files, for reference:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee

      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <display-name>HorarioLivre</display-name>

   <!-- Spring MVC -->
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>horariolivreapp</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>horariolivreapp</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.spring.web.config</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

   <!-- Spring Security -->
   <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**horariolivreap-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.horariolivreapp.controller" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**webSecurityConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xsi:schemaLocation="

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security


http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

   <http use-expressions="true">
      <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

      <form-login 
         login-page='/form_login.html' 
         login-processing-url="/usuario_login.html"
         default-target-url="/usuario_start.html" 
         authentication-failure-url="/form_login"
         always-use-default-target="true"/>

      <logout logout-success-url="/login.html" />

   </http>
   <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
         <user-service>
            <user name="user1" password="user1Pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
         </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
   </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Looking in this files, someone can find the reason for this problem?

**UPDATE 1**
This is my Controller (DispatcherServlet) class:

```
package com.horariolivreapp.controller;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.horariolivreapp.core.Sessao;
import com.horariolivreapp.data.UsuarioDAO;
@Controller
public class HorarioLivreController {

    private Sessao sessao;

    @RequestMapping("/cadastra_evento")
    public ModelAndView cadastra_evento() {
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/listagem_evento", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listagem_evento() {
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/cadastra_horario")
    public ModelAndView cadastra_horario() {
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/listagem_horario")
    public ModelAndView listagem_horario() {
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/cadastra_usuario")
    public ModelAndView cadastra_usuario() {
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/listagem_usuario")
    public ModelAndView listagem_usuario() {
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/cadastra_tipo")
    public ModelAndView cadastra_tipo() {
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/cadastra_campo")
    public ModelAndView cadastra_campo() {
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/cadastra_autorizacao")
    public ModelAndView cadastra_autorizacao() {
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/usuario_perfil")
    public ModelAndView usuario_perfil() {
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/usuario_config")
    public ModelAndView usuario_config() {
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/usuario_login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView usuario_login(@RequestParam("j_username") String username, @RequestParam("j_password") String password) {
        UsuarioDAO usuario = new UsuarioDAO(username, password);
        if(usuario.getUsuario() != null) {
            this.sessao = new Sessao(usuario.getUsuario());
        }
        return new ModelAndView("usuario_start","usuario",usuario.getUsuario());
    }
    @Configuration
    @ImportResource({ "classpath:webSecurityConfig.xml" })
    public class SecSecurityConfig {
       public SecSecurityConfig() {
          super();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you duplicating initialization (servlet + listener) in initializer and `web.xml`. Any specific reason for that or is it a mistake? Btw. that is the reason for NULL - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29

Comment: I just follow the instructions from this article: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/spring-security-login.html. I try remove the initialization (servlet+listener) from web.xml, but now the application is loaded but I receive an error **HTTP Status 404 - /HorarioLivre/**, with this detail: **type** Status report,
**message** /HorarioLivre/, **description** The requested resource is not available.

Comment: It is a bit unclear how you define your Spring contexts. Not sure whether the root configuration (some of your `@Configuration`) will load `webSecurityConfig.xml`. But most importantly you are initializing dispatcher servlet with empty context so it will never load `horariolivreap-servlet.xml` properly.

Comment: also, if i remove the initializer and keep the web.xml unchanged, i receive the same error message.

Comment: Your mapping in `web.xml` is "incorrect" I would say as it will map only `*.html`. That means `GET /HorarioLivre/` won't even reach spring's dispatcher servlet. With Spring you usually want every request to be dispatched by Spring (i.e. `/` mapping).

Comment: Ok, I change my mapping following your sugestion, but still receives the error 404.

Comment: I am working with web.xml only now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48760/discussion-between-pavel-horal-and-kleber-mota)

Answer (score 1):

An NPE at that point means that `appServlet` is null, which in turn means that `sc.addServlet(...)` returned `null`.

The Javadoc for `addServlet` says this:

> "*Returns:  a `ServletRegistration` object that may be used to further configure the given servlet, or `null` if this `ServletContext` already contains a complete `ServletRegistration` for a servlet with the given `servletName` or if the same servlet instance has already been registered with this or another `ServletContext` in the same container.*"

Now you are instantiating the `Servlet` object at that point, so it cannot have previously been registered.  But there *could* be another `Servlet` with the same name ... and that's the probable immediate cause of the problem.

And in fact, it looks like you have *already* registered a servlet called "horariolivreapp" by declaring it in the web.xml file.

Comment: Ok, how I say to Pavel above, I try remove the initialization (servlet+listener) from initializer and from web.xml. After proceed from two ways, the application is loaded, but I receive an error 404 (described in the answer above, too).